# How to share a web page in Firefox 89 (June 2021)?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser

The previous version of Firefox had three dots button (Page Actions)

[image: Firefox Page Actions]

There was an extremely useful option to share a page via AirDrop, iMessage and so on.

Smart guys from Mozilla removed this button in the new version of Firefox, which is quite annoying!

How do we suppose to share a web page now?

[image: Firefox 89 Page Actions button missing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Michael's answer I found the Share option: right click on the tab and you get it:

[image: How to share a web page on Firefox 89 (June 2021)]

Thanks guys from Mozilla for "the best" user experience.

Comment: Dang, they really know where to hide it well... Another link in the hamburger menu would've been appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

I found it by doing a ctrl+click on the tab name. It then shows a contextual menu containing the old sharing option. Not really convenient though.

Comment: For PC users that would be a right-click on the tab...